# Preposition for "un problème" + verb

Tags: prépositions

I have a problem memorizing all the countries in Europe.

> J'ai un problème ___ mémoriser tous les pays d'Europe.

I imagine we can't do without a preposition here as in the English version, so should "à" or "de" or "avec" be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use an infinitive you can use either *pour* or *à*.

> J'ai un problème pour mémoriser...
>   J'ai un problème à mémoriser...

You could use a noun :

> J'ai un problème avec la mémorisation des ...

Although *mémoriser* exists in French, we'd probably prefer to use *se rappeler* or *retenir*.

> J'ai un problème à/pour retenir...
>   J'ai un problème à/pour me rappeler ...

An alternative to *avoir un problème* would be *avoir du mal*:

> J'ai du mal à retenir tous les pays d'Europe.

Comment: Je ne vois pas vraiment le problème avec *mémoriser*. As-tu un problème avec *mémoriser* ? ;-) C'est tout autant habituel que *memorize* en anglais, il me semble.

Comment: Le mot mémoriser aurait plus de rapport avec l'action de mettre dans la mémoire, tandis que les mots "retenir" et "rappeler" auraient plus rapport avec l'action de se souvenir de quelque chose qu'on connait déjà.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait également utiliser:

> J'ai de la difficulté à mémoriser...

Ou bien,

> J'ai de la misère à mémoriser...

Mais comme Laure a déjà dit, si vous voulez utiliser "problème", ça serait:

> J'ai un problème à mémoriser...